# mysql - Count of days in a month with groupby Month data

Tags: mysql

I just need some help with below query. Have data like below in mysql table.
**Ignore the typo pls. Its Date not Data.**

[image]

My query is below.

```
Select MONTHNAME(Date) as period,  ((30*24*60)-SUM(MTTD))/(COUNT(MTTD)*1440) as MTBSI from table where Team = 'Team1' GROUP BY MONTHNAME(Date)
ORDER BY FIELD(period,'January','February','March','April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
```

This is working fine and giving me result as i wanted below.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw3et.png): 
Now in the query there is formula '(30*24*60)'--> Here 30 is days count in a month.

Question: Can you please help me with getting this days count automatically for that month. Day(Last_day(Date)) doesnt work as it probably required where clause with date range. But my query should return all monnths data aggregated dynamically. 
Am not an expert with sql so kindly ignore if its dumb question :)

Answer (score 0):

i Just had to put the same in group by clause and it worked :) . Probably was a dumb one but i am new to sql. so included Day(Month(Date)) in group by clause.